# Input array of integers: Why is there a parse error when using the read function?

Tags: parsing, haskell, io

I've been trying to learn the basics of Haskell in my spare time, but I've been stuck on debugging this little program that takes integer inputs from the user, converts them into a list of `Int`s:

```
module Main where

------------------------------------------------------------

lines_to_words_impl :: [String] -> [String] -> [String]
lines_to_words_impl output_words input_lines =
    if null input_lines then output_words
    else lines_to_words_impl (output_words ++ (words (head input_lines))) (tail input_lines)

lines_to_words :: [String] -> [String]
lines_to_words input_lines =
    lines_to_words_impl [] input_lines

------------------------------------------------------------

words_to_ints_impl :: [Int] -> [String] -> [Int]
words_to_ints_impl output_ints input_words =
    if null input_words then output_ints
    else words_to_ints_impl (output_ints ++ (read (head input_words))) (tail input_words)

words_to_ints :: [String] -> [Int]
words_to_ints input_words =
    words_to_ints_impl [] input_words

------------------------------------------------------------

load_ints_from_input :: String -> [Int]
load_ints_from_input input =
    words_to_ints (lines_to_words (lines input))

------------------------------------------------------------

main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- Now, I just grab and try to print the first integer,
    -- which is enough to cause the read/parse error:
    user_input <- getContents
    putStrLn (show (head (load_ints_from_input user_input)))
```

But when I input some numbers it always provide the same run-time error:

> Prelude.read: no parse

[demo using godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/d6e9svsTd)

In my spare time over the past month I've been continually stumped. The only place I use the `read` function is on line 19, and its input is the `head` of `input_words`, which we know is non-empty because of where we are in the if statement - and it really should be just `7` given the example inputs in the godbolt link. From what I can tell I'm using the read function correctly (see [hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Read)) to read an integer string and parse it to an `Int`.

Could someone kindly point out why this parse error is occurring?

Comment: `words` already breaks words at newline boundaries, so you can just use it in place of `lines` and throw away `lines_to_words{,_impl}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic reason is that Haskell thinks you are parsing a *list* of `Int`s, since you use:

```
output_ints ++ (read (head input_words))
```

so the type of `read (head input_words)` should be `[Int]`, you can wrap it into a singleton list:

```
output_ints ++ [read (head input_words)]
```

to solve the problem.

But this can be done more efficiently and readable with `map`:

```
lines_to_words :: [String] -> [String]
lines_to_words = concatMap words

words_to_ints :: [String] -> [Int]
words_to_ints = map read

load_ints_from_input :: String -> [Int]
load_ints_from_input = words_to_ints . lines_to_words . lines

main :: IO ()
main = do
    user_input <- getContents
    print (head (load_ints_from_input user_input))
```

Comment: @Elliott notice, `output_ints ++ (read (head input_words))` is NOT equivalent to `(output_ints ++ read) (head input_words)`. Actually,  the later wont ever compile, but the former would do if `input_words` is a list of strings, each representing a list of ints. Do not trust chatGPT that much ;)

Comment: @Elliott: chatbots have definitely an added value, but one needs to be careful: it is in fact just something that predicts words based on previous words and a certain "context". As a result these bots tends to "hallucinate": just because a sentence appears often in a certain context, they include that sentence. Even if the context turns out to be different.

Comment: @Elliott while tools like ChatGPT _can_ be useful sometimes as a learning aid, they are frequently wrong. In this case, the statement you got from ChatGPT is just pure nonsense that just happens to sound plausible enough to be believable. Be very careful when employing this type of tool.